# Is there a way to automatically bulk-update specific ID3 fields in MP3s but leave other fields untouched?

Tags: windows, mp3, music, id3

I have thousands of MP3s which are missing the "Year" ID3 field which means I can't sort albums chronologically.

I'm looking for a way to automatically download ID3 metadata in bulk and populate **only the "Year" field** of all these MP3s, leaving the other fields (Title, Album, Artist, etc.) untouched.

I've tried various Windows programs but they seem to lack the ability to selectively choose which fields you want to update and instead they try to update all fields which is undesirable for me.

Is there some method (e.g. via scripting or some other kind of automation) which would let me update only specific ID3 tag fields?

Comment: You might want to look at: https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html